# Gulp task exits before Stream can fire an "end" event

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, streaming

```
var jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var testFunc = function(platform, testType) {
  var timer = startTimer();
  console.log('started!');

  return gulp.src('./src/**/_test/**/*.mem.js')
      .pipe(jasmine({
        verbose: !!args.verbose,
        timeout: 15000
      }))
    .pipe(debug())
    .on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('started!');
      throw e;
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('end!');
      console.log(stopTimer(timer));
    });
};

gulp.task('mem', function(done) {
  testFunc('chrome', 'mem').on('end', function() {
    console.log('done!');
    done();
  });
});
```

On gulp v3.9.1.  The above code completes without ever logging "end!" or "done!" to the console.  What can I do to make that happen?

```
My console output:
> gulp mem

[13:10:39] Using gulpfile ~/foo/bar/gulpfile.js
[13:10:39] Starting 'mem'...
started!
[13:10:39] gulp-debug: src/components/avatar/_test/avatar.mem.js
[13:10:39] gulp-debug: src/factories/store/_test/store.mem.js
[13:10:39] gulp-debug: 2 items
```

**UPDATE:**

Took Lentus' advice below, which works well for synchronous tasks, like gulp-debug.  But async ones, like gulp-jasmine, the stream ends before that task completes.  You'll also note that the "Finished 'mem' after X seconds" is not printed:

```
My console output:
> gulp mem

[13:10:39] Using gulpfile ~/foo/bar/gulpfile.js
[13:10:39] Starting 'mem'...
started!
ended!
...

3 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 18.5 seconds
```

Comment: Set up the events before doing anything with the data. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hmm, so that worked... I'm curious as to why every example I see for gulp has the event handlers added at the very end of the pipe list, not the beginning?

Comment: They may be examples of longer running tasks. But in general for events you want to set up listeners as early as possible

Comment: Also, it only seems to work with "sync" tasks, like debug().  If I do an async task in there (like gulp-jasmine, which is what this process will actually end up running), the "end" even fires before that task completes...

Comment: Oh yeah, asynchronous tasks are a different beast. That's the purpose of that `done` function passed in to the `mem` task. It gives you more control over the order of events. The end is called once the pipe is done running it's code, if the code inside setups an async task the function is technically done so it fires the end event

Comment: Ok, so I edited the code above a bit.  How do I get the desired behavior - ie, fire the "done" callback only after all of the sync AND async tasks in the pipeline have completed?

Comment: I'm going to write it out as an answer gimme one sec

Answer (score 0):

[Gulp Doc Async Tasks](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support)

When you want gulp to do things asynchronously gulp provides a callback to let it know when a task is done. For example:

```
gulp.task('build', function(taskFinishedCb) {
    gulp.src("SOURCE_FILE_PATH/GLOB")
    .on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('started!');
      throw e;
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('end!');
      console.log(stopTimer(timer));
    })
    .pipe(jasmine({
    verbose: !!args.verbose,
    timeout: 15000,
    // This is the big thing you need according to the Jasmine docs
    // This specifies a callback to invoke when the tests are done
    onComplete: taskFinishedCb
  }))
  .pipe(debug())
});
```

I've seen issues with the onComplete option in Jasmine so it may not work as expected but that's how it would be done theoretically. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Just tried it - sadly, same result as before :/  Thanks for the suggestion, though!  It's interesting, when I use "return gulp.src("blah")..." it works, fine, but when I try to use either the "done" callback or return a Promise, the 'end' event gets fired out of order/not at all.

Comment: Interesting, guess I'm saving this question for later lol. And np

Comment: Oh look, there's a whole group of people that have this problem :)   https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-jasmine/issues/49  Looks like the issue is mostly gulp-jasmine specific (or rather, how I'm using it).  I guess I'll have to use gulp-exit, as suggested in the discussion.